# Cordova two custom plugins with two build-extras.gradle files

Tags: cordova, gradle, cordova-plugins

I have two custom cordova plugins in my cordova app and they both use build-extras.gradle files. Therefore i could not use both of them for same cordova app. I am looking for a way to modify plugin.xml file if the build-extras.gradle file already exists append some contents to it or otherwise copy the file. i wonder if anybody has a solution for this matter?

Answer (score 2):

the custom cordova plugins config file `plugin.xml` should use the following directive to declare their associated build-extras.gradle file:

`<framework src="src/android/build-extras.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />`

this way the 2 files won't overlap